# Derivative of the determinant applied to the identity is the trace of the derivative

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-calculus

> If $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is multilinear then $$ \frac{d}{dt}T(x_{1}(t),\dots,x_{n}(t)) = T(\dot{x}_{1}(t),\dots,x_{n}(t)) + \cdots{} + T(x_{1}(t),\dots,\dot{x}_{n}(t)) $$ Prove that, if $X(t)= (x_{1}(t), \dots, x_{n}(t))$ with every $x_i : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R^n}$ and $X(t_{0})=I_{n \times n}$, then $$ \frac{d}{dt} \det(X)(t_{0}) = \mbox{tr} \left( \dot{X}(t_{0}) \right) $$

---

I got stuck in this problem for my introduction to PDE course. Any hint?

Comment: from the first equation you write it is enough to compute $T(x_1(t_0),...,\dot x_i(t_0),...,x_n(t_0))$ where $T$ is the determinant and $x_i(t_0) = (0,...,1,...,0)$, can you take it from here?

Comment: The determinant is the product of the eigenvalues of a matrix. Use this to Taylor expand your function $det(X(t))$.

Comment: This is a special case of 
[Jacobi's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula)

Comment: @Giulio, one of my problems comes with that, because I've tried just to derivate the evaluation but is not the same as the evaluation of the derivative, for example, $sin(0) = 1$ but $(sin(0))'=(1)'=0$ and $sin'(0)=cos(0)=1$. I guess that's what you meant, if is not I just didn't get it.

Comment: no, what I am saying is that $T(x_1(t_0),...,\dot x_i(t_0),...,x_n(t_0))$ is the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix, of which all columns but one are the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$.
E.g.
$$
T(\dot x_1(t_0),x_2(t_0),...,x_n(t_0)) = \det\begin{pmatrix}
\dot x_{1,1}(t_0) & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\dot x_{1,2}(t_0) & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\dot x_{1,3}(t_0) & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots  & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
\dot x_{1,n}(t_0) & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 
\end{pmatrix}=\dot x_{1,1}(t_0)
$$ 
Summing these $n$ contributions should give $\mathrm{tr}\,\dot X(t_0)$...